# Vector of Vectors Containing Structs

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I have defined a struct

```
struct path{
    char type;
    bool visit;
    bool inPath;
    int level;
}
```

I have also defined a vector of vectors of this type struct

```
vector < vector<path> > spaceStation(numLevels*levelSize,vector<path> (levelSize));
```

I have two questions.

1) Have i defined the vector so that the number of rows pertain to (numLevels*levelSize) and columns pertain to levelSize

2) When accessing the individual elements of the vector, how can i set the elements of the struct inside it. I have tried using the .at() member function to little success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For Q1, you are correct.** 
For example: a 4x4 dimension vector.

> vector< vector< int > > vec(4, vector(4));

**For Q2, to access the path, can't you do the following:**

spaceStation[2][3] to access row 2 column 3 data, for example.

**Then you can do:**

spaceStation[2][3].visit to access elements inside your struct.

Answer (score 1):

**Re: 1**

Yes.  But I can't help feeling like you wanted to do this instead:

```
vector < vector<path> > spaceStation(numLevels,vector<path> (levelSize))
```

Note that using the term "rows" and "columns" is entirely in your imagination, concerning vectors.  You just have a vector inside another vector.  It's like an array of arrays - no special geometry implied.

**Re: 2**

Because you have a vector of vector, you need to use two indices, not just one:

```
spaceStation[level][pathindex].visit = true;
```

Where `spaceStation[level]` returns the vector at index `level`, which you then take the element at position `pathindex` (which is an instance of your struct), and finally modify a value in that struct.